# What does that mean on SignalR KeepAlive value "This value must not be more than 1/3 of the DisconnectTimeout value"?

Tags: c#, timeout, signalr

I am storing the signalR connection in DB but when a user disconnect, it will not update the connection statues until 30 seconds which is the default value. If something is sent in this period, the client will not receive it.

I don't want to change the disconnect timeout to 6 seconds which is the minimum because keep alive will be 2 seconds which is not needed.

can i set the disconnect timeout to 6 seconds then set the keep alive to 10? why is this warning about setting the keep alive to a value bigger than disconnect timeout?

Comment: Can you explain why you're storing the connections in a DB and what exact problem you're trying to solve with the timeouts? If it's related to the connection loss, it is usually simpler to update/refresh a status on a reconnect... usually this is already done when the data is initially retrieved.

Comment: @Stefan, there are 2 goals of storing the details of the connection in DB. 1- supporting multiple devices for the same user. 2- Logging and ensuring that the service and users are connected correctly. I know that we can use groups but we need to retrieve the data instead of keeping it in the ram of the server

Comment: Certain protocols like Websocket in IIS, under heavy load, would terminate WebSocket connection stating lack of communication between communicating parties, keeping Keep-Alive to 1/3 or somewhat less keeps empty packets flowing through them thus keeping connection open.